# Replace a value in object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following array :::

```
WC_Cart Object (
  [cart_contents] => Array (
    [d6f5bb0bbc] => Array (
      [product_id] => 14
      [variation_id] => 325
      [variation] => Array (
        [Your Build] => Windows
      )
      [quantity] => 1
```

How would I go about replacing ( updating ) `[quantity] => 1` to say `[quantity] => 3` :::

Any assistance would be appreciated :::

**Update >>> More Info. to make things clearer**

Below is the hook ( woocommerce_calculate_totals ) I want to access to change values in the printed array above that originates from `print_r($this);` :::

I'm not sure how to create the function I need to update the value with `add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'my_quantity' );`

I have worked with arrays & hooks before but this is a bit out of my league :::

// Allow plugins to hook and alter totals before final total is calculated

```
do_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', $this);                   

            /** 
             * Grand Total
             *
             * Based on discounted product prices, discounted tax, shipping cost + tax, and any discounts to be added after tax (e.g. store credit)
             */

$this->total = apply_filters('woocommerce_calculated_total', number_format( $this->cart_contents_total + $this->tax_total + $this->shipping_tax_total + $this->shipping_total - $this->discount_total, 2, '.', ''), $this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actions and filters in WordPress, they are different:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

In WooCommerce there are two very similarly named action/filter:

- woocommerce_calculate_totals action
- woocommerce_calculated_total filter

`woocommerce_calculate_totals` actions are called with the cart object, so what you should do (and hopefully should work) is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'my_quantity' );

function my_quantity( $wc_cart ){
  $wc_cart->cart_contents['d6f5bb0bbc']['quantity'] = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what you wanted?

```
$wc_cart->cart_contents['d6f5bb0bbc']['quantity'] = 3;
```

A few examples of accessing arrays and objects:

```
$object->some_property
$object->{'complex'.'property'.'name'.(2*3)}
$array[12]
$array['hello']
$array[ $array_index*10 ]
```

Learn more about arrays and objects at:

- Arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- Objects: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: It's not working for me ::: but this could mean I have other issues as I'm using it in an action hook ::: I'll do some testing tomorrow THX for your input :::

Comment: You have to change the `$wc_cart` variable name to your actual variable, and it should work (if I understood the output of your `print_r` well :)

Comment: I don't understand I thought that `$wc_cart` is the variable I'm supposed to use ::: I updated the post with additional info. maybe it helps explaining what I'm supposed to do ::: THX

Answer (score 0):

First get `cart_contents` out of the object, then work your way through the arrays:

```
$wc_cart->cart_contents['d6f5bb0bbc']['quantity'] = 3;
```